# How do I reuse the same Runnable for two separate method calls

Tags: java, android, multithreading, callback, runnable

I want to make a 2 method call using a separate thread. At the moment I call directly like this:

```
class A implements Listener
{
    private void callOne()
    {
        object.methodOne(FruitEnum.APPLE, this);
    }

    private void callTwo()
    {
        object.methodTwo(VeggieEnum.CARROT, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Result result)
    {
        // prints the result after getting called back from the Listener
    }
}
```

I can create my own `Runnable`.

```
private static class MyRunnable implements Runnable
{
     @Override
      public void run() 
      {
           object.methodOne(FruitEnum.APPLE, listener);
      }
}
```

The problem is, **how would I re-use the same Runnable for two separate method calls**? Do I create new instances of `MyRunnable` and give it different parameters? There has to be a clean way of doing this.

Do I simply create a Runnable per method call? One for `methodOne()` and one for `methodTwo()`. This feels like bad coding to me.

Comment: Try removing `static` from the inner class and instead instantiate two different threads?

Comment: If I instantiate two different threads how do I say, one `run()` does one thing, the other `run()` will do something else?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with creating two `Runnable` instances. But you can pass a parameter in the constructor like you suggested.

Comment: This is what I would expect.  If not, then what would be the point of multithreading?

Comment: I don't mind creating a new instance. I just need a clean way of telling my thread to execute different code. If I can avoid it I will not like to pass anything in a constructor.

Comment: Your question may in fact be an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) where you ask "how do I fix this code problem" when the best solution is to use a different approach entirely. Consider telling us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I need to call two different methods from a separate thread. And I would like to reuse the same `Runnable` instead of creating 2 different `Runnables`.

Comment: That's an implementation detail, and not what I'm asking for. I'm asking for the behavioral details since again, the best implementation might be totally different.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It seems that the problem I am solving is an implementation specific problem.

Comment: Indeed that's your question. I'm trying to raise it out of this realm, if only to understand the actual underlying problem better, but it's all your call.